# Como declarar uma classe e como definir valores da mesma?

Tags: javascript, funções, classes

Eu estou tentando fazer um simulador de pokemon similar ao [Pokémon Showdown](https://pokemonshowodown.com), porém eu estou fazendo do zero. Além de ter as funções de um jogo de pokemón comum, terá algumas personalizadas.

Gostaria de saber como eu faço para declarar uma classe e como definir valores a mesma.

Em C# após ter declarado o modelo da classe e o novo valor a ela `Pessoa numero01 = new Pessoa();` por exemplo, é só usar como exemplo `numero01.nome = "José";`.

De acordo com as minhas anotações, não é a mesma coisa. E agora quando tento definir o valor da seguinte forma aparece `undefined`.

```
class Move { 
   constructor(info, spUsage, atkUsage, baseDamage, name, secEff, accuracy, instaFail, pp)
   {
    this.info = info; 
    this.spUsage = spUsage;
    this.atkUsage = atkUsage;
    this.baseDamage = baseDamage;
    this.name = name;
    this.secEff = secEff;
    this.accuracy = accuracy;
    this.instaFail = instaFail;
    this.pp = pp;
   }
   getMoveData(value)
   {
    //retorna o valor da propriedade inserida. Ex: iceBeam.getMoveData(name); retorna 'Ice Beam'
    return value;
   } 
   setMoveData(data, value)
   {
    //onde 'data' seria um valor da classe como 'info' e 'value' seria o valor para associa-lo ao mesmo como 'true' ou '11' etc.
    data = value;
   }
}

//Começo da database dos movimentos
iceBeam = new Move();
iceBeam.setMoveData(spUsage, true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O conceito de utilizar os membros da classe está errado.
No construtor da classe, são definidas várias propriedades, como `info` e `spUsage`, isso está ok. Agora os métodos de "set" devem fazer set a esses valores, por exemplo:

```
setSpUsage(value) {
     this.spUsage = value;
}
```

Ai tem alguns erros:

- getMoveData está retornando o mesmo value que recebeu por parâmetro, isso não faz sentido;
- setMoveData está igualando os dois valores que recebeu por parâmetro, o que também não faz nenhum sentido.

Neste caso para atribuir precisa ou passar os valores no construtor, por exemplo `var iceBeam = new Move(1,2,3,4....);` ou setar diretamente o valor (`iceBeam.info = "teste"`) ou criar métodos set como o exemplo acima, alterando os valores da própria classe.

Veja esse exemplo:

```js
class Move { 
   constructor(info, spUsage, atkUsage, baseDamage, name, secEff, accuracy, instaFail, pp)
   {
    this.info = info; 
    this.spUsage = spUsage;
    this.atkUsage = atkUsage;
    this.baseDamage = baseDamage;
    this.name = name;
    this.secEff = secEff;
    this.accuracy = accuracy;
    this.instaFail = instaFail;
    this.pp = pp;
   }

   setSpUsage(value) {
     this.spUsage = value;
   }
}

// definido o valor de "info" no construtor
var iceBeam = new Move("info",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null);
// definido o valor de "name" diretamente na propriedade
iceBeam.name = "teste";
// definido o valor de "spUsage" usando um método
iceBeam.setSpUsage(true);
// resultado
console.log(iceBeam);
```

Comment: Podia fazer uso de [setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) e [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) também, que entraram no ES6

Comment: @Ricardo Pontual, a minha classe tem vários valores, não teria uma forma de fazer com que a `function set` fosse universal? Ou seja, ela "setasse" todos os valores necessários da classe?

Comment: "universal"? se usar no construtor pode passar todos os valores, ou fazer direto `iceBeam.accuracy, iceBeam.... etc`

Comment: @RafaelTavares sim boa sugestão, eu declarei um set para demonstrar a diferença de como funciona e como esta o outro set declarado na classe, mais para ilustrar.